# Nach einem Aufschlag von 5% kostet ein MP3 Player 94,50 euro?

Tags: translation

I need correct translation for this sentence what does it means a rise of a price by 5% or decrease of price by 5%

Nach einem Aufschlag von 5% kostet ein MP3 Player 94,50 euro

Comment: Is that "Aufschlag" in effect because someone did something wrong (e.g. not paying in time) or just because things get more expensive over time? In other words: is the "Aufschlag" a fee (like a penalty or a fine)?

Comment: It's as a result of rise of price

Comment: You can read in every dictionary, what »Aufschlag« means. ==> Close Question

Comment: @user22634 If you already know that it is the result of the **rise** of a price, how can you ask whether it means a "rise of a price by 5% or decrease"??

Comment: Thorsten Dittmar That was just a guess . from what I have read in the question I thought it might mean rise or decrease but I wasn't sure which one is the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an increment of 5% on the price...